# Array constants aren't working as expected in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I was trying to use an array constant to do some calculations.  I saw this thread: [Array Constants in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256674/array-constants-in-excel), but I am using the array constant within the formula so it is not relivant. If I use `=SUM({1,2,3})` the result is `6` as expected.  However,if I use it with `DCOUNT`, it doesn't work as expected:

```
      A
 1 Colour
 2 Red
 3 Yellow
 4 Green
 5 Red
 6
 7 Colour
 8 =Red
```

The result of `=DCOUNT(A1:A5;;A7:A8)` is 2.

The result of `=DCOUNT(A1:A5;;{"Colour";"=Red"})` is **#Value!**.  The error message is **Value used in formula is wrong data type.**

Is this some inconsistency in MS Excel 2010?  Or have I done something wrong?

#### EDIT

It was suggested that "=Red" was the issue, but the reference to [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/more-arrays-introducing-array-constants-in-excel-HA001087291.aspx) page at heading *Elements you can use in constants* IMO doesn't really expain it.  If it were the issue however, then the following should work:

```
      A
 1 Number
 2 1
 3 2
 4 3
 5 1
 6
 7 Number
 8 1
```

The formula `=DCOUNT(A1:A5;;A7:A8)` gives `2`, but the formula `=DCOUNT(A1:A5;;{"Number";1})` or `=DCOUNT(A1:A5;;{"Number";"1"})` both still give the same error as my previous example.

Comment: The `DCOUNT` formula specifically requires a range instead of an array constant.  The same is true for all of the database formulas.

Comment: Is there documentation to support this?

Comment: Check out the section "Elements you can use in constants" in [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/more-arrays-introducing-array-constants-in-excel-HA001087291.aspx). I think it explains why you can not use the `"=Red"` formula inside the constant array.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek, so your saying that even though `=Red` is a string, it has to be a formula for `DCOUNT` to work?  If that were the case, I should be able to replace each colour with a number and it should work.  I'll update post above.

Comment: @Adrian see here for documentation: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dcount-HP005209049.aspx Quote from that page: `You can use any range for the criteria argument, as long as the argument includes at least one column label and at least one cell below the column label in which you specify a condition for the column.`

Comment: Sorry that did not help... And I do not know the answer, but could help you with approaches that yield the same result using different functions :-)

Comment: @tigeravatar, `{"Number";"1"}` contains a column label i.e. `"Number"` and one cell below the column label i.e. `"1"`.

Comment: No, that is an array constant, not a range, and as such it will not work.  It has to be a range because the database formula can check against multiple columns (which is a 2-dimensional array). Because array constants are one-dimensional arrays, the database formulas can't use them.  It has be a range of cells.  Your own tests have already shown that this is the case.

Comment: @tigeravatar Array constants can be 2 dimensional as seen [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/more-arrays-introducing-array-constants-in-excel-HA001087291.aspx).  Though the use of the word `range` does make me suspect that you're on the right track, it is still vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A range *can* be used as an array but an array *cannot* be used as a range.

Since `DCOUNT` specifies only a range parameter, an array constant is illegal type for that parameter.

According to these pages:

- [Introducing array formulas in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx)
- [Putting advanced array formulas to work](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/putting-advanced-array-formulas-to-work-HA001087227.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001087290)

they would imply that array constants are to be used with items that do not take ranges but:

1. Either an array, which would result in a single value 
   *-or-*
2. Single values, resulting in array (***Ctrl-Shift-Enter** must be used to generate the array result*)

To do what I was trying to do (count all of the cells that contained the string `Red` in range A2:A5), I would do something like this:

```
      A
 1 Colour
 2 Red
 3 Yellow
 4 Green
 5 Red
```

`=SUM(IF(A2:A5="Red", 1, 0))` which would count the number of *Red* entries by creating the intermediate array `{1;0;0;1}` and then add all the elements together resulting in `2`.